# Lyapunov stability dynamic systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

$\dot{x}=-(x-1)\cdot(x-2)^2$

I want to find the stability with the 2 Lyapunov methods ( linearization and appropriate Lyapunov function).
I solved similar exercises with the first method of linearization but I don't understand how to solve this because is not a system of two equations. Is there a variable change involved?
And also I don't understand how to choose a suitable Lyapunov function. Thanks!

Comment: It is not a system of two equations, you have only one variable and your state matrix $A$ is a scalar.

Comment: So the eigenvalue will be -1 for point x=1 and 0 for point x=0? And how can I choose a Lyapunov function for this?

Comment: Why do you study point 0? It is not an equilibrium.

Comment: Define $z=x-1$ and consider $V=\frac{1}{2}z^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The system comprises two equilibrium points $x=1$ and $x=2$

To study the first equilibrium point $x=1$,  consider the variable transformation $z=x-1$. Then the original dynamical system is rewritten as follows:

$$\dot{z}=-z(z-1)^2$$

Let $V(z)=\frac{1}{2}z^2$. Its time derivative:
$$\dot{V}(z)=z\dot{z}=-z^2(z-1)^2<0\;\;\forall\;\; |z|<1$$

then the equilibrium point $z=0$ (or equivalently $x=1$) is stable.

For the second equilibrium $x=2$, we can not construct a Lyapunov function because it is not stable.